# Front derailleur wont shift to small gear

Tags: derailleur, front

I have removed the cable and loosened the range adjustment screws to take them out of the picture.

Spring on front derailleur now pushes the cage all way to left. Looks correct so chain should move to smallest gear. But just stays on middle gear and rubs cage.  Won't hop.

Nothing is jamming the cage from moving inward; it is at max inward and lined up with inner gear. Its not bent nor mounted too high. Everything looks correct.

Any ideas?

Comment: Some clarifications - has it ever worked ?  Has the front mech been changed at any point in the past?   Have you had any accidents or collisions on this bike?  Is it possible someone's kicked your bike when its been parked?    It is possible that some photos might help show more.   Use [edit] to add photos to your question.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the derailleur is clean and nothing is jamming the mechanism that is preventing the cage from moving inboard.

Make sure the derailleur is mounted with the cage parallel to the chainrings, and isn't mounted to high.

Possibly the cage is bent.